# InstallShield won't over-write a file during an upgrade

Tags: installshield, installscript-msi

In my OnFirstUIAfter function, I rename a file that was just installed, using:

```
RenameFile(FileName1, FileName2);
```

In my OnMaintUIAfter function, I install FileName1 again, but it needs to over-write     FileName2, just as it did in the initial install.  If I simply use:

```
RenameFile(FileName1, FileName2);
```

Nothing happens.  I still have both files in the INSTALLDIR, and FileName2 is out of date.

Believing that there's a problem with the installer script not being able to rename an existing file, I have since determined to delete the file prior to the rename.

```
DeleteFile(FileName2);
RenameFile(FileName1, FileName2);
```

And still nothing happens.  Both files are still in the INSTALLDIR.

Keep in mind that FileName2 is not a file being installed by any previous install.  All the installs install FileName1 and then rename it to FileName2.

Any words of wisdom?  I'm completely out of ideas.

SH

Comment: Have you checked the return codes from your calls to RenameFile and DeleteFile? Is it possible you're passing it the wrong path, or calling it without enough privileges for it to succeed?

Answer (score 2):

My best words of wisdom would be to stop writing custom actions.  Learn the [component rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [file versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rules and let MSI do the heavy lifting for you.   Out of process custom actions will only muddy the waters.

Comment: You're right. MSIs have product code GUIDs and not individual files. After I wrote that, I came to the conclusion about 5 minutes later that I had confused some things. However, I know from writing MSIs in Visual Studio that unless the version is explicitly marked as greater that the MSI will not replace the existing file with the new one (at least under default). I have, however, never had this problem with installscript in InstallShield.

Comment: @Christopher - I understand the component and versioning rules.  I had 4 different files, but only one should be installed depending upon the system settings.  I didn't want to leave it up to the user to choose their component when InstallScript should be able to do it for them.  I ended up putting the 4 files in separate folders on my PC, and installing them without renaming.  In either case, this was a pain.

Comment: Custom actions are rarely a good choice.  You should examine Feature and Component Conditions along with DuplicateFile table entries to achieve the desired result while not violating MSI best practices.